# xml files in drawable directory? Surely some mistake?

Tags: android

I am attempting to get and advertisers system incorporated into my android app. There are a selection of files (within a tree of directories) that I have been instructed to copy into my projects resources folder. Most of the files & directories make sense... except for the fact that inside their "drawable" directory they have a selection of XML files (along with the expected PNG files). To me this looks like a cock-up. Surely all the XML files should be within the "layout" directory?

Comment: Why on earth is this question getting marked down? Its an innocent question with a clear answer. Isn't it?

Comment: Even Android uses them, e.g. the [btn_default](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default.xml) drawable

Comment: Thanks for the up-votes.. back to zero now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's perfectly valid. You can have XML drawables [see docs about this here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) - read about it - these are quite powerful and flexible. Moreover, you should avoid putting other types than XML based drawables into `res/drawables` folder. All the bitmaps should be stored into `res/drawables-<QUALIFIER>` (i.e. `res/drawables-hdpi`, `res/drawables-mdpi` etc folders).